# Defining Kant's idea of the sublime and applying it to a painting?

Tags: kant, aesthetics

How would one go about applying Kant's idea of the dynamical sublime to a painting  as to Kant the Dynamical sublime is:

> The dynamically sublime is similar. In this case, a “‘might' or power is observed in nature that is irresistible with respect to our bodily or sensible selves. Such an object is 'fearful' to be sure, but (because we remain disinterested) is not an object of fear. (God is fearful but the righteous man is not afraid)”(Kant).  Such objects are objects that ’raise the soul's fortitude above its usual middle range and allow us to discover in ourselves an ability to resist which is of a quite different kind...' (sect.28). In particular, nature is called 'sublime merely because it elevates the imagination to the exhibition of those cases wherein the mind can be made to feel the sublimity, even above nature, that is proper to its vocation' (sect.28).

Is it that the painting is initially fearful but no an object of fear as we remain disinterested?  We feel the sublime from resisting this feeling?

Can someone explain Kant's idea of the dynamical sublime?  How does the dynamical sublime relate to the definition? ... As 
The sublime feeling is therefore a kind of 'rapid alternation' between the fear of the overwhelming and the peculiar pleasure of seeing that overwhelming overwhelmed”.

Comment: Welcome to Phil.SE! You might find it useful to add a little more detail  where the quotes are sourced from - 'sect.28' doesn't tell the community which work of Kants you're referencing.

Comment: My guess would be *critique of judgment* based on the terms.